# Installing ubuntu on Wyse C50LE with 1GB storage

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I'm trying to instal a ligter vesion of ubuntu on a WyeC50LE thincient which has 1Gb RAM and 1Gb Flash storage. I choose ubuntu minimal of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr" 31MB. And I'm having trouble with the kernel which throws an error while installing the base system. I require a ubuntu distribution that can be instaled on a Wyse C50LE thin client, which will be running a virtalization client.

Comment: *What error? Please tell us the details*, otherwise we can only guess and not really help.

Comment: 14.04 is very old. I would try 18.04 or tinycore

Comment: The error was cannot install kernel to target system. But now I have it installed. It asked for a kernel selection and I selected the  generic trusty tahr and it installed successfully but now not able to install bootloader. So I did continue anyway

Comment: 1 GB RAM is not enough to run standard Ubuntu. And 1 GB flash storage is not enough to store the files of any Ubuntu family desktop flavour (not even the light-weight Lubuntu). You can play with [Xubuntu Core 18.04](https://unit193.net/xubuntu/core/) live-only, but if you want to run some real tasks, you need a smaller operating system, for example Tiny Core, as suggested by @Panther.